# How to extend a child interface element?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is an external interface definition which I'm importing into my file:

```
export interface WorkspaceJsonConfiguration {
    version: number;
    projects: {
        [projectName: string]: ProjectConfiguration;
    };
    defaultProject?: string;
}
```

Now I need to extend `ProjectConfiguration` by adding two fields:

```
import { WorkspaceJsonConfiguration, ProjectConfiguration } from '@nrwl/devkit'
interface ProjectConfig extends ProjectConfiguration {
    version: string
    date: string
}
```

But this seems to be wrong as it doesn't extend `WorkspaceJsonConfiguration`, which I'm using in my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [module augmentation and declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) is what you're looking for. It will allow you to augment the `ProjectConfiguration` interface with your custom properties:

```js
import { ProjectConfiguration } from '@nrwl/devkit'; // Don't forget this import

declare module '@nrwl/devkit' {
  interface ProjectConfiguration {
    version: string
    date: string
  }
}
```

Now when working with your `WorkspaceJsonConfiguration` objects you'll notice that each `project` will be prompted for the extra fields you augmented.